# Constantly reading and writing pipe works one way and just once in the other

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, raspberry-pi4

I'm writing a program in C++ on a Raspberry Pi 4 to command some motors and get back the informations of speed sensors through the GPIO pins.

To do so, there is a main control program with a "fork" in it.
The parent process does all the calculation and the child process is constantly sending and receiving data through a SPI communication (sending and receiving data are done at the same time and the library don't allow to do either one or the other).

On each loop, the child reads data sent by the parent (this part works) and it sends back the data read on the inputs (works once) to the parent.

I actually have the "read" data wired with cables so I can control the inputs and be sure of their states.

In the following example, I give the requested infos to the program to have the parent write to the child, which works (choosing motor 0/15, having a speed of 0 and a direction 0=stopped and not stopping the program)

On the first try, it tells me the read data is 10, which is correct.

I then move my jumping cables to another value (15 in this case) but it still gives me 10 on the second try

I checked my program, the write from the child receives the good data, it is really the piping that has a problem and I can't get my head around it. It looks like the Pipe gets closed...

Here is the terminal view

[image: Terminal window]

The problem is between the parent lines

```
if (read(fdCP[0], In0, sizeof(short int)*2) == -1) { std::cout << "Something went wrong in Parent read :'( " <<'\n'; }
```

and the child lines

```
 //If here I print the content of "In0", it is correct and fitting what the program read
 if(write(fdCP[1], In0, sizeof(short int)*2) == -1) { std::cout << "Something went wrong in child write :'( " <<'\n'; }; //sending data through the pipe
```

And here is the programm stripped down of its vast majority for readability.

```
#include <bcm2835.h> //SPI & GPIO communication library
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>     //got fork() in it
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream> //for Cout to display stuff
#include <thread>   //for multithreading
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

using std::vector;
int SRDInit();
char* SendReceiveData(char* SpiOut, char* SpiIn); //Defines the existance of this function and will check in the compiled stuff if it exists (spoiler : it does)
int SRDClose();
int main(int MotNb, int Spd1, int Dir1)
{
    //Fork and multiprocessing stuff
    bool EndThis = false;   //Variable for ending the continous look of sending and receiving data from shift registers
    //SPI Communication buffers and data storages
    char SpiOut[2]={0,0}; //Defining the char to send by SPI and set it to 0
    short int In0[2] = {0}; //Char array for receiving data
    int Sp1 = 0;        // iteration variable for speed
    short int SpdDir[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0}; //creates a table with 4 ints inside 0 for motor number, 1 for Speed, 2 for Dirrection and 3 for killing the child

//###################################################################################   
//Actual beginning of the program
//###################################################################################
        int fdPC[2];            //File descriptor for the piping Parent to child
        int fdCP[2];            //File descriptor for the piping Child to Parent
        std::cout << "Init FD" << '\n';
        if (pipe(fdPC) == -1){          //creating the pipe for communication with the second program sending and receiving data
            //fd[0] = Read fd[1]=write
            std::cout << "an error occured while creating the pipe Parent to Child" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        if (pipe(fdCP) == -1){          //creating the pipe for communication with the second program sending and receiving data
            //fd[0] = Read fd[1]=write
            std::cout << "an error occured while creating the pipe Child to Parent" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
        std::cout << "Forking" << '\n';
        int id = fork();        //forking the program to create a second one playing on another processor
        std::cout << "Forked ID = " << id << '\n';
        if (id < 0){
            std::cout << "An error occured while forking :'(" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (id > 0){           //if in the main process
            std::cout << "Enter Main process" << '\n';
//###################################################################################   
//Main process.
//###################################################################################
            close (fdPC[0]);        //closing the read side of the Parent to child pipe
            close (fdCP[1]);        //closing the write side of the child to parent pipe
            fcntl(fdPC[1], F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(fdCP[0], F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            int MotNb = 0;          //variable for the number of the motor to be modified
            short int OldIn0[2] = {0, 0};
            short int NewIn0[2] = {0, 0};
            
            while(EndThis == false){
                std::cout << "Gi'me Motor 0-15" <<'\n';
                std::cin >> MotNb;
                std::cout << "Gi'me speed" <<'\n';
                std::cin >> Spd1;
                std::cout << "Gi'me dirrection 0=3= stop 1=fwd 2=bwd" <<'\n';
                std::cin >> Dir1;
                std::cout << "Stop that? Y/N" <<'\n';       //check if we want to close the program
                std::cin >> EndProg;
                
                SpdDir[0] = MotNb;          //storing the Motor number
                SpdDir[1] = Spd1;           //storing the speed
                SpdDir[2] = Dir1;           // storing the dirrection

                if(write(fdPC[1], SpdDir, sizeof(short int)*4) == -1) { std::cout << "Something went wrong in Parent write :'( " <<'\n'; }      //Writing through the pipe to send data to the Child
                if (read(fdCP[0], In0, sizeof(short int)*2) == -1) { std::cout << "Something went wrong in Parent read :'( " <<'\n'; }

                NewIn0[0] = In0[0];
                NewIn0[1] = In0[1];
                if (NewIn0[0] != OldIn0[0] || NewIn0[1] != OldIn0[1]) {
                    std::cout << "SOMETHING CHANGED !!! Old In0 = " << +OldIn0[0]<< +OldIn0[1] << " and NewIn0 = " << +NewIn0[0]<< +NewIn0[1] << '\n';  
                    OldIn0[0] = NewIn0[0];
                    OldIn0[1] = NewIn0[1];
                }
                
                if (SpdDir[3] > 0){
                    EndThis = true;
                    std::cout << "Stopping main" <<'\n';        //check if we want to close the program
                }
            }   //End of PARENT while
            write(fdPC[1], SpdDir, sizeof(int)*3);      //Writing through the pipe to send data to the Child for ending the program
            //End of main program, closing everything and freeing memory because we're tidy people
            close (fdPC[1]);        //closing the write side of the Parent to child pipe
            close (fdCP[0]);        //closing the read side of the child to parent pipe
            if (wait(NULL) == -1){              //wait for the child to finish working == -1
                std::cout << "No children to wait for" << std::endl;
            }else {
                std::cout << "waiting for children to finish" << '\n';
            }
        }
        else{                   // if in the secondary process
            std::cout << "Enter child process" << '\n';
//###################################################################################   
//Child process. Send Speed and dirrection requested and receive data (because no choice for receiving)
//###################################################################################
            close (fdPC[1]);        //closing the write side of the Parent to child pipe
            close (fdCP[0]);        //closing the read side of the child to parent pipe
            fcntl(fdPC[0], F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            fcntl(fdCP[1], F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
            
            int MotNb = 0;          //variable for the number of the motor to be modified
            //Actual beginning of child program
            char* SpiIn=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*17);     //creation de la data qui sera échangée malloc est fermé apres l'appel a la fonction
            if(SpiIn==NULL){
                perror("Char allocation of SendReceiveData FAILED !!");
                return 1;
            }
            while(EndThis == false){
                read(fdPC[0], SpdDir, sizeof(short int)*4);//read data from the pipe put them in SpdDir varaible
                MotNb = SpdDir[0];          //storing the motor nb
                Spd1 = SpdDir[1];           //storing the speed
                Dir1 = SpdDir[2];           // storing the dirrection
                
        //Some amazing coding has been deleted here ;)

                    In0Raw = SendReceiveData(SpiOut, SpiIn);        //Send data in "SpiOut" and puts the data received in In0Raw
                    In0[0] = In0Raw[1];     //Data is no read in the logical direction TBC
                    In0[1] = In0Raw[0];     //Data is no read in the logical direction TBC

                //If here I print the content of "In0", it is correct and fitting what the program read
                if(write(fdCP[1], In0, sizeof(short int)*2) == -1) { std::cout << "Something went wrong in child write :'( " <<'\n'; }; //sending data through the pipe
                sleep(1);
                if (SpdDir[3] > 0){
                    EndThis = true;
                std::cout << "Ending child" << '\n';
                }
            }   //End of CHILD while
            //End of child program, closing everything and freeing memory because we're tidy people
            close (fdPC[0]);        //closing the read side of the Parent to child pipe
            close (fdCP[1]);        //closing the write side of the child to parent pipe
            free(In0Raw);           //free memory allocated to In0Raw for "SendReceiveData"
            std::cout << "Child ended" << '\n';
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    
//###################################################################################
    if (id > 0){
        std::cout << "End of program enter a key and press ENTER to finish" <<'\n';
        std::cin >> Spd1;
        SRDClose();
        free(In0Raw);       //release memory of the pointer just in case
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you're wondering what "SendReceiveData" is, it's just a very tiny function sending and receiving data through the SPI connection. It works fine, it's really basic ;)

I know where the problem lies, but I have absolutely no idea what the problem is. It looks like the pipe is closed wfter writing it once from Child to Parent, but it works very fine in the other direction, to send instructions from Parent to Child

(If needed, I can copy the whole code instead of this extract)

Thanks by advance for your help ! :)

Comment: You don't handle the case where `read` returns a number greater than zero but less than `sizeof(short int)*2)`. You don't even check for this condition, so your code will just silently fail. Also, you set the descriptors non-blocking, so you will pass the `read` line even if you read nothing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The values over 0 and under `sizeof(short int)` are the values I want to read and stored in `In0`... no? . For the "non blocking", the goal is to have the child run in circle non stop and when something is to be read, to take it in account, so it's (kind of) ok same for the parent ^^,

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, my neurones just connected. I've checked the read and write for errors over 0, and there is some... But, where can I find what these errors mean? I asked internet without success now :/

Comment: Ok, so, the write side gives me a `Ressource temporarily unavailable` when getting the error with `strerror(errno)`... I guess it means the pipe closed or the write side closed as the "read" of this same pipe gives `success`. But... i'm not closing the pipe nor the file descriptor. Any hint?

Comment: You need code to correctly handle the case where you go to read a bunch of bytes and either no bytes or fewer than that number of bytes are currently available. You don't have any code to handle those cases right now.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz any hint on what kind of code? :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz "POSIX.1 says that write(2)s of less than PIPE_BUF bytes must be atomic". Read can ever only return 0 or `sizeof(short int)*2` bytes as PIPE_BUF is 4096 here. It can return 0 though, that must be checked.

Comment: You are missing `SpdDir[3] = EndProg == "y";` so you never tell the child to quit, the sole reason for the 4th short. Inside the parent loop you write 4 shorts while after the loop you only write 3 shorts from SpdDir. That is inconsistent. The child always tries to read 4 shorts. But with `SpdDir[3]` fixed by that point the child would already have stoped before reading, you told it to die. So who is going to read those last 3 shorts?

Comment: Let me recommend some changes: Make SpdDir and In0 structs so you have members with names that show meaning instead of indexes. Remove the `O_NONBLOCK` so reads wait for the other process to write, otherwise you need `select`, `poll` or `epoll`, which makes no sense for a single FD. Create wrapper functions for read/write that check for `EINTR` (+`EAGAIN`, `EWOULDBLOCK` if non blocking) and repeat or fail with `perror()`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't think there's a guarantee that a short read won't occur. But even so, he has the same problem if no data at all is available.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are correct, you have to check the return, always. It immediately and frequently returns 0.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow After a C++ --> English translation, I can answer. In my program, I wanted the child to contently read the data as I can't know when the data input will change and can't check if it changed. And the parent would read when it is possible for it to get the actual state of the data. I know that's not the most efficient way of doing, but at my level of testing/development it seemed quite ok. Isn't there a way to do this? Constantly updating data from a "child" and reading from time to time from 1 or more threads/parent? Anyway, my program needs a lot of development ;)

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow For the changes you recommend, I forced the parent to send a data of `SpdDir[3] = 0` so there is something to read. Except that, I think the rest is overkill, `SpdDir = Speed Direction` (of motors ;) ) `In0 = Input (data) 0`, they show meaning ^^, I had an explanation of what structs are and I think my simple small variables are nice for what I do :) Also, `if(write(fdCP[1], In0, sizeof(short int)*2) == -1)` will actually write something in the FD, so if I check it 5 different times, it writes 5 times... How is that handled? I put the result in a variable? O.o

Comment: Posix guarantees that small writes will be atomic. So the write either writes all or nothing. So you just need to retry till it succeeds once unless there is a real error. As for using structs: That's a readability and maintainability issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read the documentation (given by a friend) [write() manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) which did not help, but can be useful to someone.

I tried to understand the error, using `errno` for which I checked the documentation [errno manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and was useful.

The write() sent back the error "Resource temporarily unavailable" which corresponds to "EAGAIN" but, most importantly it is said "may be the same value as EWOULDBLOCK"
corresponding to "Operation would block"

I searched and found a discussion where the answer was "the buffer is full"

So, I asked if it is possible to overwrite a data in the write() file descriptor and the answer is "no" :'(
[Is it possible to overwrite a write() data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71472542/can-write-in-a-pipe-overwrite-its-content-before-read-occurs?noredirect=1#comment126327936_71472542)

You have to read a data in a file descriptor before writing again.

Apparently, threads are better for that, I have to invesstigate.

Hoping this helps someone.